# How to get latest values for each group with an Elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some documents indexed on Elasticsearch, looking like these samples:

```
{'country': 'France', 'collected': '2015-03-12', 'value': 20}
{'country': 'Canada', 'collected': '2015-03-12', 'value': 21}
{'country': 'Brazil', 'collected': '2015-03-12', 'value': 33}
{'country': 'France', 'collected': '2015-02-01', 'value': 10}
{'country': 'Canada', 'collected': '2015-02-01', 'value': 11}
{'country': 'Mexico', 'collected': '2015-02-01', 'value': 9}
...
```

I want to build a query that gets one result per country, getting only the ones with `max(collected)`.

So, for the examples shown above, the results would be something like:

```
{'country': 'France', 'collected': '2015-03-12', 'value': 20}
{'country': 'Canada', 'collected': '2015-03-12', 'value': 21}
{'country': 'Brazil', 'collected': '2015-03-12', 'value': 33}
{'country': 'Mexico', 'collected': '2015-02-01', 'value': 9}
```

I realized I need to do aggregation on `country`, but I'm failing to understand how to limit the results on `max(collected)`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use a [`top_hits`](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation that groups on the `country` field, returns 1 doc per group, and orders the docs by the collected date descending:

```
POST /test/_search?search_type=count
{
    "aggs": {
        "group": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "country"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "group_docs": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1,
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "collected": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you not get an error like: "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [country] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.? If yes, how did you resolve it?

Comment: Hi, for some reason we get an exception: "reason": "No search type for [count]" can you help me?

Comment: Hi this option is today obsolete as u can see in the following: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/no-search-type-for-count/101994/2

Comment: Hi, what if i want to say that if the last result of any country is of date today i want to exclude the whole country?

Comment: 2020 here. Worked great, version 7.4. I added an answer showing how to add extra filters.

Answer (score 2):

For those like [user1892775](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1892775/user1892775) who run into "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default...", you can create a multi field (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html). So you might have mapping like:

```
"mapping": {
    "properties": {
      "country": {"type": "string", "fields": {"raw": {"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"}}}
}
```

Then your query would look like

```
POST /test/_search?search_type=count
{
    "aggs": {
    "group": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "country.raw"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "group_docs": {
                "top_hits": {
                    "size": 1,
                    "sort": [
                        {
                            "collected": {
                                "order": "desc"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

(Note the use of country.**raw**)

Answer (score 2):

The answer marked correct worked great for me. **Here is how I added some extra filters.** This is version 7.4 on AWS.

The field I'm grouping by is a keyword field named tags.

- For each group (tag), get top 3 documents sorted by date_uploaded descending.
- Also show the total amount of documents within each group (tag).
- Only consider non-deleted documents belonging to user 22.
- Only return 10 groups (tags), sorted alphabetically.
- For each document, return its ID (book_id) and date_uploaded. (Default is that all info is returned.)
- Size:0 keeps the query from returning lots of info about all the documents.

  ```
    {'query': {'bool': {'filter': [{'terms': {'user_id': [22]}}, {'terms': {'deleted': ['false']}}]}},
     'size': 0,
     "aggs": {
        "group": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "tags.keyword",
                "size":10,
                "order":{ "_key": "asc" }
            },  
            "aggs": {
                "group_docs": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 3,
                        "_source":["book_id","date_uploaded"],
                        "sort": [ {"date_uploaded": { "order": "desc" }}]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  ```

  }

Here is how to get each group (tag in my case) and the document matches for each group.

```
query_results = ... result of query
buckets = query_results["aggregations"]["group"]["buckets"]
for bucket in buckets:
    tag = bucket["key"]
    tag_doc_count = bucket["doc_count"]
    print tag, tag_total_doc_count
    tag_hits = bucket["group_docs"]["hits"]["hits"]
    for hit in tag_hits:
        source = hit["_source"]
        print source["book_id"], source["date_uploaded"]
```

FYI, the "group" term can be named anything. Just make sure to use the same name when getting buckets from your query results.