# ELK query to return one record for each product with the max timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

On Kibana, I can view logs for various products (product.name) along with timestamp and other information.  Here is one of the log:

```
{
  "_index": "xxx-2017.08.30",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "xxxx",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "v": "1.0",
    "level": "INFO",
    "timestamp": "2017-01-30T18:31:50.761Z",
    "product": {
      "name": "zzz",
      "version": "2.1.0-111"
    },
    "context": {
      ...
      ...
    }
  },
  "fields": {
    "timestamp": [
      1504117910761
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1504117910761
  ]
}
```

There are several other logs for same product and also several logs for different products.

However, I want to write a query that returns single record for a given product.name (the one with maximum timestamp value) and it returns same information for all other products. That, is logs returned one for each product and for each product, it should be the one with maximum timestamp.

How do I achieve this?

I tried to follow the approach listed in:
[How to get latest values for each group with an Elasticsearch query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016271/how-to-get-latest-values-for-each-group-with-an-elasticsearch-query)

And created a query:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "group": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "product.name"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "group_docs": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1,
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "timestamp": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

But, I got an error that said:

```
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [product.name] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."
      }
    ],
```

Do I absolutely need to set fielddata=true for this field in this case? If no, what should I do? If yes, I am not sure how to set it. I tried doing it this way:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/xxx*/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "properties": {
      "product.name": { 
        "type":     "text",
        "fielddata": true
      }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "group": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "product.name"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "group_docs": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1,
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "timestamp": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

But, I think there is something wrong with it (synatactically?) and I get this error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [properties].",
        "line" : 3,
        "col" : 19
      }
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you got error is because you try to do aggregation on text field (product.name) you can't doing that in elasticsearch 5.
You don't need to set field data to true,what you need to do is define in the mapping the fields product. name as a 2 fields, one product.name and second product.name.keyword 
Like this:

```
{
 "product.name": 
      {
         "type" "text",
          "fields":
             {
                "keyword": 
                   { 
                     "type": "keyword",
                     "ignore_above": 256
                    }
             }
         }
   }
```

Then you need to do the aggregation on product.name.keyword

Comment: Lax, I had infact just tried replacing "field": "product.name" in my query above to "field": "product.name.keyword" after posting this question and that was atleast not failing and seemed to return correct records. Do we really need to use the whole big section above as you wrote above instead of just replacing product.name with product.name.keywrod? If yes, why? And how do I include that in my current query above?

Comment: The whole big section need to be in your schema. Please post your schema