# How can i get the ALL lastest record with each group by Elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have reference from this [how-to-get-latest-values-for-each-group-with-an-elasticsearch-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016271/how-to-get-latest-values-for-each-group-with-an-elasticsearch-query)

and now i do the search, but the aggregations only return 10 doc for me, how can it show all match result? I ONLY show two since its too long for the return repsonse , thanks!

my ES query is :

```
{
    "size" :1,
    "aggs": {
    "group": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "studentId"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "group_docs": {
                "top_hits": {
                    "size": 1,
                    "sort": [
                        {
                            "timestamp": {
                                "order": "desc"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

and the result:

```
{
    "took": 32,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 10000,
            "relation": "gte"
        },
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "data",
                "_type": "class",
                "_id": "N-wsrHYB4zCrGLTdS7Ur",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "studentId": 144,
                    "timestampstring": "2020-09-02 05:58:04.828",
                    "type": "data"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "group": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 99670,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": 131,
                    "doc_count": 579,
                    "group_docs": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 579,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": null,
                            "hits": [
                                   {
                                    "_index": "data",
                                    "_type": "class",
                                    "_id": "SVVj4HYBlaUrIoJst3-o",
                                    "_score": null,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "studentId": 131,
                                        "timestampstring": "2021-01-08 13:06:34.413",
                                        "type": "data"
                                    },
                                    "sort": [
                                        1609340059767
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": 147,
                    "doc_count": 529,
                    "group_docs": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 529,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": null,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "data",
                                    "_type": "class",
                                    "_id": "SVVj4HYBlaUrIoJst3-o",
                                    "_score": null,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "studentId": 147,
                                        "timestampstring": "2021-01-08 13:06:34.413",
                                        "type": "data"
                                    },
                                    "sort": [
                                        1610082394413
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the [size param](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-size) in the terms aggregation

> The size parameter can be set to define how many term buckets should
> be returned out of the overall terms list.

```
{
  "size": 1,
  "aggs": {
    "group": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "studentId",
        "size": 100                // note this
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "timestamp": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 1:**

You can use [stats bucket aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-stats-bucket-aggregation.html), to get the count of unique `studenid`

```
{
  "size": 1,
  "aggs": {
    "group": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "studentId",
        "size": 100 // note this
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "timestamp": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "bucketcount": {
      "stats_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "group._count"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks you! can i also ask how to count how can i count how many "unique" studentId can i get in this query? @ESCoder

Comment: @ManManYu please go through my updated answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: yes but i need to wait three minute to press the "Tick": sign ,,,, =P

Comment: @ManManYu glad I could help you 